# connect with likeminded people and build networks (translation)

Tags: traduction, anglais

Ok, I'm working on a translation (just to practice my French) and have come to a point where I cannot tell, whether or not my translation is actually correct. To me "entrer en contact avec" and "améliorer nos réseaux" make sense, but is that how these expressions are actually used? 
I'll provide you with the original text and my translation so far. I tried not to stick to the text too closely but still include the most relevant information.

*English*

> This year we want to connect with as many likeminded people as possible. Together, we want to learn new things, build stronger networks and discuss alternatives to current ways of life in order to look after our climate better. And during our "days of action" we want to point the way for climate justice – together.

*French*

> Cette année nous voulons entrer en contact avec le plus grand nombre de personnes partageant le même état d'esprit que nous. Ensemble, nous voulons en apprendre et en proposer plus, nous voulons améliorer nos réseaux et nous voulons discuter d’alternatives au notre mode de vie, parce que nous devons prendre soin du climat et de l’environnement. Pendant notre « journées d’action » nous voulons indiquer la route à suivre pour atteindre la justice climatique.

P.S.: I'm new to this forum and don't know my way around yet. I'm sorry if the formating is off or if I should have posed my question differently. Thanks so much for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Entrer en contact* and *améliorer<sup>1</sup> nos réseaux* are fine and might be used by native people.

As a side comment, while your text is quite good French, there are a few issues like these ones :

- *en apprendre et en proposer plus* doesn't seem to match "learn new things" and the two *en* are odd here.
- ***au*** notre mode de vie is incorrect, should be ***à*** notre...
- *parce que nous devons* doesn't translate "in order to".
- *notre* needs to agree with *journées*
- we do not use German quotes *„xxx“* but guillemets *« xxx »* <sup>2</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Instead of *améliorer*, *renforcer* or *consolider* would better match *stronger*.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Azaghal corrected your question in the meantime.</sub>

Comment: _améliorer nos réseaux_ is definitely fine but in this context I would prefer _renforcer nos réseaux_ to keep the idea of strength of the original text.

Comment: @Azaghal Yes, *renforcer* can be used here, *consolider* too.

Comment: @Azaghal Thanks a lot for your feedback! Sorry about the quotations marks, I completely forgot. I now made the following suggested changes: _renforcer nos réseaux_, _à notre_ and  _nos journées_ ...

Comment: @Azaghal I understand that _parce que nous devons_ doesn't translate to "in order to" but think it won't make much of a difference? 
I also changed _en apprendre et en proposer plus_ to _apprendre de nouvelles choses_ but I'm not sure if that works. It sounds a little too simple, but maybe that's what's best?
Also, thank you @jlliagre!